# How to change MainActivity element from BroadCastReceiver

Tags: android, kotlin

I've a BroadcastReceive and want to change/display the text of the views in the `MainActivity` based on the logic in the broadcast

```
class Receiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
         // somthing like
        // MainActivity.layout.latitudeTxt = ....
   }
}
```

My `MainActivity` is as below:

```
private lateinit var layout: View
private lateinit var latitudeTxt: TextView
private lateinit var longitudeTxt: TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        layout = main_layout
        latitudeTxt = latitudeText
        longitudeTxt = longitudeText
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add a broadcast receiver with a custom listener programmatically, not inside an AndroidManifest. You will need these classes:

```
class Receiver(val receiverListener: ReceiverListener) : BroadcastReceiver() {
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    // somthing like
    // MainActivity.layout.latitudeTxt = ....
    receiverListener.doSomething()
}
```

}

You can change this interface to make it suitable to your requirements(add methods, change it's signatures e.g.). This is a classic callback technique.

```
interface ReceiverListener {
    fun doSomething()
}
```

And then register you receiver in `onCreate()`:

```
    receiver = Receiver(object : ReceiverListener {
        override fun doSomething() {
            //If you need to change smth related to UI
            runOnUiThread {

            }
        }
    })
    registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter("YOUR_ACTION"))
```

Don't forget to unregister in `onDestroy()`

Comment: Thanks, you mean I've to call the receiver from the activity I'm in, and destroy it once I leave it! what about if I need the receiver to  keep running regardless the active activity, and its response to be varies based on the active activity itself!